# manage large array php

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

Advanced custom fields gives me this large array. Id like to be able to use a php include or require to manage these chunks of code more effectively ie: include the 'header code', 'google analytics' etc. These arrays can get really large and managing them is becoming a key part in wordpress theme development (for me anyway).

These arrays create fields in wordpress. I want to be able to switch the fields on and off. Some sites I build the fields are not required. If the file was smaller and more manageable, i could easily see what is and what is not required.

Is there a way to manage these large array's?, as simply using an include to include a chunk of code does not work

```
<?php
  if(function_exists("register_field_group")) {
      register_field_group(array (
      'id' => 'acf_options',
      'title' => 'acf options',
      'fields' => array (
          // header code 
          array (
              'key' => 'field_header_code',
              'label' => 'header code',
              'name' => 'header_code',
              'type' => 'textarea',
              'column_width' => '',
              'instructions' => 'use for google fonts',
              'default_value' => '',
              'placeholder' => '',
              'prepend' => '',
              'append' => '',
              'formatting' => 'html',
              'maxlength' => '',
          ),
          // google analytics
          array (
              'key' => 'field_google_analytics',
              'label' => 'Google analytics',
              'name' => 'google_analytics',
              'type' => 'textarea',
              'column_width' => '',
              'instructions' => 'Dont include script tags',
              'default_value' => '',
              'placeholder' => '',
              'prepend' => '',
              'append' => '',
              'formatting' => 'html',
              'maxlength' => '',
          ),
          // footer js 
          array (
              'key' => 'field_before_closing_body_js',
              'label' => 'Footer js - before closing body tag',
              'name' => 'before_closing_body_js',
              'type' => 'textarea',
              'column_width' => '',
              'default_value' => '',
              'instructions' => 'Dont include script tags. footer js,  Avanser js goes here',
              'placeholder' => '',
              'prepend' => '',
              'append' => '',
              'formatting' => 'html',
              'maxlength' => '',
          ),
  ),
  'location' => array (
    array (
    array (
        'param' => 'options_page',
        'operator' => '==',
        'value' => 'general-options-global-stuff',
        'order_no' => 0,
        'group_no' => 0,
    ),
    ),
  ),
  'options' => array (
  'position' => 'normal',
  'layout' => 'no_box',
  'hide_on_screen' => array (
  ),
  ),
  'menu_order' => 0,
  ));
}
```

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the arrays? "Manage"  is a little vague.

Comment: I have expanded my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serialize()` to convert any object into a string that can be written to a file then later reloading the object back into memory exactly as it was using `unserialize()` Read about them on php.net